# Set repeating alarm

Tags: java, android

i want to set alarm to repeat it in a particular day .for example every monday at 4:20 ,
I have created a method but not working .please help me to solve this problem

```
public void setAlarm(int day,int hour,int minit){

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minit );
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Long alarmTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 *7, pendingIntent);

}
```

now if i choose monday 2:40 its only alarming on next monday 2:40 not working on every monday 2:40

Comment: What about it isn't working? Explain the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You can try use [setInexactRepeating](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) instead.As of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact.You can refer to the [official documents](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use setInexactRepeating  function it worked for me.